# How to undo the last thing a user typed in a text field when he/she presses a button?

Tags: python, text, widget, undo

If the user clicks a menu button it would trigger a function that would undo what the user last typed. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: First show your code. Second: what GUI do you mean - PySide, PySQ, wxPython, Tkinter, HTML ? what button do you mean - 'UNDO' ? 'OK' ?

Comment: Tkinter and I don't need help making the button I already have that set up I just can't figure out how to make the undo part I have the function ready its just the undo part I need help with.

Comment: To make undo you have to remember what was in text field before - that's all.

Comment: @furas I don't want to undo every thing they typed. I am trying to make it undo the last word or letter they typed. How would I get them?

Comment: Bind function to "on key pressed" and remeber all pressed keys.

Comment: You need to search for `Command Pattern`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509129/do-undo-using-command-pattern-in-python and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

Comment: something like this `textWidget.bind("<Key>", function)`

Comment: @furas Ok thanks also how would would I Delete selected text in a text field I have tryed self.Cont.focus_get().event_generate("<<Delete>>") but it does not work is there another way to delete selected text?

Comment: Probably you could use `insert()` with special tags to add empty string in place of selected text.

Comment: Try tags `SEL_FIRST` and `SEL_LAST` - see more in [Tkinterbook](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm)

Comment: Try to insert empty string in place of selected text with something like this `textWidget.insert(SEL_FIRST, SEL_LAST, '')`

Comment: I add example hot wo delete selected text. You will have to check if text is selected :)

Comment: @furas I have stored what the user types in a string but how would I search for it in the text field?

Comment: Get all text from text field and search normaly in Python.

Comment: And read Tkinterbook http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm - maybe you find something better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monitor every keystroke in the text box and save the content of the text box after each change in a stack structure. When you encounter a word delimiting character replace the individual character changes for that word that are already on the stack with a new entry that is the whole word just typed. When the user presses undo you just pop the last value off the stack and put that in the text box.

This will allow you to undo individual character changes one at a time when the user is in the middle of typing a word and will undo the last whole word if the user completed typing it.

Answer (score 0):

How to delete selected text

```
from Tkinter import *

def clear():
    if txt.tag_ranges(SEL):
        txt.delete(SEL_FIRST, SEL_LAST)

master = Tk()

txt = Text(master)
txt.pack()

bt = Button(master, text='Delete selected', command=clear)
bt.pack()

master.mainloop()
```